# MySQL Query issue; Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'

Tags: mysql, pdo

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong with my following query;

```
SELECT 
main.id as id, d.name as departmentName, s.name as sectionName, m.fullName as fullName, main.title as title, main.entryDate as entryDate 
FROM pre_tickets as main 

INNER JOIN pre_ticketscategory as d ON d.id = main.mainCategory_id 
INNER JOIN pre_ticketscategory as s ON s.id = main.category_id 
INNER JOIN pre_members as m ON m.id = main.member_id  

WHERE 

main.softDelete = '0' AND 
main.parent_id = '0' AND 
main.status = '0' AND 
(main.id LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR d.name LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR s.name LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR m.fullName LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR main.title LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR main.entryDate LIKE '%my_query_ł%') 

ORDER BY main.id desc 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

**Error**

```
Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'
```

**All 3 tables are (including fields);**

**Character Set:** UTF-8

**Collation:** utf_8_general_ci

I'm using PDO (I also ran the query directly from PHPMYAdmin and Navicat with the same results). I use UTF-8 for my connection (`SET NAMES utf8` command).

I don't have this problem when I don't use JOINS.

If I remove **ł** then everything works as expected, no errors. However if I don't I get the error. Shouldn't UTF-8 character set along with utf_8_general_ci collation support such characters?

**Note:**

Here is the weird part;

1. If I don't use **ł** in my query then my query works

   (main.id LIKE '%my_query%' OR d.name LIKE '%my_query%' OR s.name LIKE '%my_query%' OR m.fullName LIKE '%my_query%' OR main.title LIKE '%my_query%' OR main.entryDate LIKE '%my_query%')
2. If I do use **ł** in my query and remove main.id and main.entryDate fields from the query then my query still works;

   (d.name LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR s.name LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR m.fullName LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR main.title LIKE '%my_query_ł%')
3. If I don't use **JOINs**, I get to use **ł** and still keep id and entryDate fields in my query without any problem.

   SELECT id, title, entryDate 
   FROM pre_tickets

   WHERE

   softDelete = '0' AND 
   parent_id = '0' AND 
   status = '0' AND 
   (id LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR title LIKE '%my_query_ł%' OR entryDate LIKE '%my_query_ł%')

   ORDER BY id desc 
   LIMIT 0, 25

**id** is `integer` field while **entryDate** is `datetime` field.

I'll be really glad if someone could explain me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is your character UTF8 encoded? Where do you get it?

Comment: What character set is your _connection_ using?

Comment: I added few details to my question. Thank you for bringing these subjects up. @Wrikken I use UTF-8 character set for my connection. @Mathieu; Well I run the query directly from PhpMyAdmin as you see it above. When I don't use joins, then the same query works as expected.

Comment: Just to experiment, could you try converting tables and fields to UTF-16?

Comment: While we're experimenting: a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename` also sometimes shows that columns can be in a different character set then the table's default....

Comment: @Haralan; I got the same results as UTF-8. @Wrikken; I set / double check the fields charset and collation as a habbit after having an issue with it about a year ago. I just double checked with `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename` query and everything seems just right.

Comment: Turns out the problem is `main.id LIKE '%my_query_ł%'` and `main.entryDate LIKE '%my_query_ł%'`. main.id is int and entryDate is datetime fields. I really don't get why using Joins it creates such problem while without Joins it doesn't. If I remove them from my query then the query works! If I don't remove them but I don't use **ł** the query still works!

Comment: What is the full error message? What is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables?

Comment: @YourCommonSense firstly thank you for your reply. I wrote the full errors message in my question; `Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'`

Comment: @Revenant for two days, I was stacked with the same problem. Just want to ask if you manage to find a permanent solutions works with JOINs?

Comment: @YahyaE I haven't actually fixed it however, I found the problem. Unfortunately I had to remove integer fields from the query. That did the trick.

Comment: @Revenant I ended up with almost same :) But removing just datetime fields worked for me. I have no problem with integers.

Comment: @YahyaE thanks, I didn't try removing just datetime fields. I will give it a shot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answer, I decided to answer to my own question;

I haven't actually fixed it however, I found the problem and make the query work as much as possible without getting error.

My solution was to remove all integer fields from the query. This way I didn't get any errors. It wasn't a good solution but at least it still allowed me to search some fields without getting an error.

I hope this helps.